# Node Application not writing to the correct griddb cluster

Tags: nat, griddb

I have a griddb cluster installed on wsl(unbuntu) on my windows laptop and another on my virtualbox vm(centos). I've used NAT in the network settings for the vm so I can enable port forwarding for ssh and for db connections from my app which is also running on my laptop within the wsl environment.

I've exposed the cluster on my vm over `127.0.0.1:30001` and the cluster on my laptop is on `127.0.0.1:10001` however I've noticed some unexpected behavior, whenever my app is writing data to the db it's writing to the cluster on my laptop even though it has the connection string to point to my vm!

But, if I stop the griddb service on the vm my app isn't able to write to any db at all. How can I correct this?

Screenshot of the last inserted record

[image]

App config

```js
const factory = griddb.StoreFactory.getInstance();
        const store = factory.getStore({
            "notificationMember": '127.0.0.1:30001',
            "clusterName": "myCluster",
            "username": <username>,
            "password": <password>
        });
```